# ASP.NET MVC: How do I validate a model wrapped in a ViewModel?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, validation, asp.net-mvc-2

For the login page of my website I would like to list the latest news for my site and also display a few fields to let the user log in. So I figured I should make a login view model - I call this `LoginVM`.

`LoginVM` contains a `Login` model for the login fields and a `List<NewsItem>` for the news listing.

This is the `Login` model:

```
public class Login
{

    [Required(ErrorMessage="Enter a username.")]
    [DisplayName("Username")]
    public string Username { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage="Enter a password.")]
    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    [DisplayName("Password")]
    public string Password { get; set; }

}
```

This is the `LoginVM` view model:

```
public class LoginVM
{
    public Login login { get; set; }
    public List<NewsItem> newsItems { get; set; }
}
```

This is where I get stuck. In my login controller, I get passed a `LoginVM`.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Login(LoginVM model, FormCollection form)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        // What?
```

In the code I'm checking whether `ModelState` is valid and this would work fine if the view model was actually the `Login` model, but now it's `LoginVM` which has no validation attributes at all.

How do I make `LoginVM` "traverse" through its members to validate them all? Am I doing something fundamentally wrong using `ModelState` in this manner?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your ViewModel try doing this:

```
public class LoginVM
{
    [Required]
    public Login login { get; set; }
    public List<NewsItem> newsItems { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: This seems to work and I will accept the answer as soon as SO lets me. But what is really happening here? Is this a hack to make ASP.NET MVC validate the `Login` instance?

Comment: @Deniz Dogan - Basically if the ModelBinder can't make a new Login(), validation fails.  No hacks.

Comment: Nope, this is not a hack, actually this is how de model validation works in V2 of MVC. Check out this blog post http://bradwilson.typepad.com/blog/2010/01/input-validation-vs-model-validation-in-aspnet-mvc.html?utm_source=feedburner&utm_medium=feed&utm_campaign=Feed%3A+BradWilson+%28Brad+Wilson%29

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively if the newsItems are for display purposes, and don't need validating, then you can pass through just the Login model to your action method.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Login([Bind(Prefix = "Login")]Login model)
{
    if (!Model.IsValid)
}
```

You will also want to use the EditFor and LabelFor helpers in your View.

```
<%= Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Login.Username) %>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
i'd like give you a modal solution:

 @if (Request.IsAuthenticated)

              {
                  <li class="span3">
                      <a href="Home/AboutMe" role="button" class="btn" data-toggle="modal">[@Membership.GetUser().UserName]</a>
                      </li>
                      <li>@Html.ActionLink("logoff","LogOff","Account")</li>
                 }
              else
              {
                   <li class="span3">
                      <a href="#myModal" id="Login" role="button" class="btn" data-toggle="modal" >Login</a>
                   </li>
              }

<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">

            <div class="modal-dialog">
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel"> Login </h4>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-body">
                        <form class="form-horizontal">
                            <div class="control-group">
                                <label class="control-label" for="inputEmail">Email</label>
                                <div class="controls">
                                    <input type="text" id="inputEmail" placeholder="Email">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="control-group">
                                <label class="control-label" for="inputPassword">Password</label>
                                <div class="controls">

                                    <input type="password" id="inputPassword" placeholder="Password">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="control-group">
                                <div class="controls">
                                    <label class="checkbox">
                                        <input type="checkbox">
                                        Remember me
                                    </label>
                                    <button type="submit" class="btn">Sign in</button>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </form>
                    </div>
```